# Why is my else passing through

Tags: c#, if-statement

So basically for class we are using an if else where the user inputs a string and if that string is correct we assign a value to a specific variable. My code seems to be fine, but for some reason when I run it and test using the exact strings the program runs through the if and goes to the else, and prints the else even though our if is true. Here is my code: (I initialized all of the variables at the beginning and did not include them here.

value = Console.ReadLine();

```
        if (value == "ATX")
        {
            number1 = 3;
        }
        if (value == "XTS")
        {
            number1 = 34;
        }
        if (value == "CTS")
        {
            number1 = 2;
        }
        else
        {
         number1 = 0;
        }

Console.WriteLine(number1);
```

So basically if i enter ATX or XTS I get number1 = 0, but if I do the CTS then number1 = 2. What is going wrong here?

Comment: agree with the below answers. the ELSE only applies to the last IF statement. You want
If...
ElseIf....
ElseIf...
Else...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually when you pass `"ATX"` or `"XTS"`, your code will set the value of `number1` variable to "3" or "34".But you are **overwriting** the value of `number1` variable again with your last `if-else` block.

Use `else if` throughout

```
if (value == "ATX")
{
    number1 = 3;
}
else if (value == "XTS")
{
    number1 = 34;
}
else if (value == "CTS")
{
    number1 = 2;
}
else
{
    number1 = 0;
}
Console.WriteLine(number1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's also easy to get the syntax wrong in such a way that the syntax is fine but the logic is not.

Use a different construct to prevent that. Here is an example:

```
String value = Console.ReadLine();
int number1;

switch (value)
{
    case "ATX": number1 =  3; break;
    case "XTS": number1 = 34; break;
    case "CTS": number1 =  2; break;
    default:    number1 =  0; break;
}

Console.WriteLine(number1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one if and the rest "else if". Then for the last use "else".